# While loop terminates without changing the condition's value

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm using this code:

```
    public void menu() {
        boolean finish = false;
        while (!finish) {
            // print menu
            int n = // acquire selection through other method of the program
            switch (n) {
                case 0:
                    finish = true;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // do stuff 1
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // do stuff 2
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // do stuff 3
                    break;
                case 4:
                    // do stuff 4
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

I tried putting `finish = true;` right before all the `break;` but the while loop keeps terminating.
The `finish` variable is NOT used anywhere else.

I need this to not terminate until `n == 0`

Comment: > I tried putting finish = true; right before all the break;

Comment: When I run your code (assigning some value to `n`), the loop runs infinitely (can't prove that, but it runs until I interrupt the program). Can't reproduce

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only want to terminal when n = 0

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean finish = false;
    while (!finish) {
        // print menu
        System.out.println("NEXT!");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        switch (n) {
            case 0:
                finish = true;
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("1");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("2");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("3");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("4");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Code above works

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WhileTest whileTest = new WhileTest();
        whileTest.menu();
        System.out.println("Just finished menu function");
    }
}

class WhileTest {
    public void menu() {
        boolean finish = false;
        while (!finish) {
            // print menu
            int n = 0; // acquire selection through other method of the program
            switch (n) {
                case 0:
                    finish = true;
                    System.out.println(0);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // do stuff 1
                    System.out.println(1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // do stuff 2
                    System.out.println(2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // do stuff 3
                    System.out.println(3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    // do stuff 4
                    System.out.println(4);
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("After the switch block");
        }

    }


}
```

Please note that you have not given any default condition in the switch statement. And when you do not give the default statement in the switch block, the code would be perfectly valid. However, the execution of the program begins after the switch block.

Note down the following scenario:

**Scenario1:** When you give n = 0. The output would be the following :

```
0
After the switch block
Just finished menu function
```

It goes the first time to the switch block and makes the finish variable to true. So execution will happen only once.

**Scenario2:** when you give n = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. The output would be the following :

```
4
After the switch block
4
After the switch block
4
After the switch block
```

It will be infinite stream of the above 2 two lines. The finish variable is never made true. You will have to manually stop the program.

**Scenario3:** when you give n = 5 or anything which is not there in the case block. The output would be the following :

```
After the switch block
After the switch block
After the switch block
After the switch block
After the switch block
After the switch block
```

It will be an infinite stream of the above lines. Because it is not going to any of the case blocks nor the variable finish is getting modified anywhere.